# Byebug not responding to commands?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, byebug

I have been having an issue lately. When trying to debug anything I run my file and use Byebug. However when I run any command on Byebug my main menu command line of terminal appears. Ex:

*****$: ruby file.rb

require "byebug"

debugger

1: def array(array_1, array_2)

```
if array_1 == array_2
   
    true 

else 
    
    false 
end
```

end

(byebug) c

*****$:

Comment: Would you be able to provide a complete code sample, so I could ideally **REPRODUCE** this behaviour? Since you redacted critical information from the code, I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Also note that [`c` is an alias for `continue`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug#byebugs-commands), so you may be seeing the *expected* result of running that specific command? (But you said it happens when you run **any** command??)

Comment: edited the code above hope that helps and yes any other command... 's' gives me the same result

Comment: `s` is an alias for `step`, as per my above link. So again, that is the **expected** result. Once again, I'll ask: Does this *really* happen for **ANY** command?